# How to combine two arrays that are generated using numpy into one

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am going to combine two arrays that are generated by using numpy.
The code I used numpy to create two arrays is shown below:

```
pop_size_1=[1,782]
pop_size_2=[3,782]
initial_population_1 = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.0, size=pop_size_1) 
initial_population_2 = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.5, size=pop_size_2)
```

The output is shown below:

```
initial_population_1: 
[0  0   0 ...  0  0  0]
initial_population_2: 
[[0.46761868 1.31375367 1.46020285 ... 1.05608653 1.49644183 1.42876581]
 [0.16272459 0.36838564 0.42397672 ... 1.02172183 0.62390021 0.99000535]
 [0.26880805 0.66085658 0.36217062 ... 0.34964188 1.3519369  1.44852434]]
```

So could you please tell me how to combine those two lists into one?
Just like this:

```
[[0  0   0 ...  0  0  0]
 [0.46761868 1.31375367 1.46020285 ... 1.05608653 1.49644183 1.42876581]
 [0.16272459 0.36838564 0.42397672 ... 1.02172183 0.62390021 0.99000535]
 [0.26880805 0.66085658 0.36217062 ... 0.34964188 1.3519369  1.44852434]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
np.vstack([initial_population_1, initial_population_2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want an appended structure having a shape (4,782).

`np.concatenate(initial_population_1,initial_population_2)`